# for in loop in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**console in IE 11**

[image]

**console in Chrome**

[image]

If I change word 'item' in the loop to 'anotherItem' like this

```
var obj = {
    id1: 'item 1',
    id2: 'item 2',
    id3: 'item 3'    
};
for (anotherItem in obj){
    console.log(anotherItem);
}
```

The cycle works fine

Why IE 11 does not process word 'item'

Comment: You should write the code in your question, not as an image like you attached in the question.

Comment: `for (var item in obj){
    console.log(item);
}` should work as expected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`item` is defined as a native function in IE, and is probably read-only, and therefore is the reason you cannot change it's value.

Prior to Edge, Microsoft didn't like adhering to standards, and introduced all sorts of features that aren't in the standards. The `item` function is not present in Edge.

Also, you haven't declared `anotherItem`, try this:

Try this:

```
var obj = {
    id1: 'item 1',
    id2: 'item 2',
    id3: 'item 3'    
};

for (var anotherItem in obj){
    console.log(anotherItem);
}
```

If you don't declare a variable with the `var` keywork, and you're not in strict-mode, it will be defined as a global variable (which is not what you want). Global variables are essentially properties on the global object, and in the context of a web browser, that'd be the `window` object.

Add the following to the top of your JS file to enable strict mode, and then you won't be able to make these mistakes in the first place as an exception will be thrown.

```
"use strict";
```

You can also choose to enable strict mode for specific functions, like this:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    // code here is in strict mode
})()
```

Comment: Maybe I did not quite correctly put the question, but I realized that it is native, but I did not understand why they did so and for what it answers

Comment: Microsoft was terrible at following web standards prior to Edge. That'll be the reason for the random function that no other browsers have.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example for old browsers. good luck.

```
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
fruits.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += index + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: OP was asking about iterating through properties of an object rather than elements of an array.